# Iseka/tensei manga with boy prince and elf assassin maid

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

MC is a baby boy prince and has a girl guide telling him he will be assassinated on his nth bday. The girl guide teaches him magic etc. and his maid as he grows. His mom and him live off royalty grounds and he finds a secret room where it has records of assassinations. His elf maid is the one who will kill him. Also, he ran into a forest and met a wolf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is [*Fuguushoku to Baka ni Saremashita ga, Jissai wa Sorehodo Waruku Arimasen?*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/128786/Fuguushoku_to_Baka_ni_Saremashita_ga_Jissai_wa_Sorehodo_Waruku_Arimasen?q=People%20Looked%20Down%20on%20Me%20for%20Having%20a%20Crummy%20Job%20but%20It%20Really%20Isn%27t%20All%20That%20Bad%3F&cat=manga), also known as *People Looked Down on Me for Having a Crummy Job but It Really Isn't All That Bad?*

The main character is reincarnated as the son of a king, and is immediately banished to an estate in the middle of a dangerous forest with his mother.  They are placed there since the job/class he was assigned at birth was considered useless. The angel/guide who helped him reincarnate teaches him the basics of the world, including some magic. There are a few servants at the estate, including an elf maid.

After a few years, he uses his skills to sneak into a locked room.  Inside is a single bookshelf of books, which contain records of people who have been assassinated.  At the end of one of the books, he finds his name, along with his mother's.  The date and method of assassination were left blank.  Talking with the guide, he decides to escape around his 10th birthday, which is when another son will be born to the king.

A day or so before his 10th birthday, he overhears the elf maid being given the order to kill the target. So, he runs off into the forest, where he befriends a wolf.

Comment: omgwd. thank you so much! I kept on searching for it but only mushoku came up. I knew it had something to do with a job!

Comment: @isekaiMangalatestobsession you're welcome.  I may also have something of an isekai manga obsession. or at least, my answers on this site tend to for isekai manga.